# Are functions allowed in SQL Server's Import/Export Wizard?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, import-from-excel

I am using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to transfer data from an Excel file into a table. I wrote the following query in the wizard's query option:

```
Select
    ISNULL([Col 1], [Col 2]),
    [Col 3]
FROM [myExcelWorkSheet$]
```

It says this SQL Statement is not a query. In fact, no other functions seem to work, such as COALESCE and even CAST.
Does the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard not accept functions?

Comment: Never tried using ISNULL during this process but perhaps you need to name the column? As is that derived column has no name which will likely cause the import wizard to choke.

Comment: I initially tried giving it an alias, but I was getting the same error without it. So I figured that wasn't the issue.

Comment: Try replacing ISNULL with IFNULL or COALESCE.

Comment: Nope. COALESCE gives the same issue. I can't use any functions. Even CAST.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the schema of the function. It must be something like this:

```
Select
    ISNULL([Col1], [Col2]),
    [Col3]
FROM [dbo].[myExcelWorkSheet$];
```

Comment: I don't think so. I can select columns if I get rid of the function. Also, this is an excel file on my desktop. Not in a db.

Comment: Wait a minute. You one to add only particular columns from your excel file? If this is the case, do the manipulation in second sheet and then import the two new columns.

Comment: If doing it in multiple steps, why not just dump the sheet, unaltered, into a table, then query/manipulate certain columns? The thing is though, I would like to eventually make this a scheduled job. So making this 1 step seems important.